# compare date between 2 dates and do in function of

Tags: php, date

I am trying to find out how to make this script work?

Basically if the difference between the date stored into the db and today's date is greater then 10 days then the links should be in red if not they should be in black.

```
<?php
    // Today's date
    $today          = date("d/m/Y"); 

    // The date stored into the DB
    $NewsDate           = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($getInfo['date']));

    // The date stored into the DB + 10 days
    $NewsDatePlus10     = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($NewsDate) + (86400 * 10)); 

    if ($NewsDate <= $NewsDatePlus10) {
        echo    "<span class='list-group-item-heading'><b>". utf8_encode($getInfo['title'])."</b><br /></span>";
        echo    "<span class='list-group-item-text'>". utf8_encode($getInfo['content'])."&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>". date("d/m/Y", $getInfo['date'])."</small></span>";                           
    } else {
        echo    "<span style='color:red;'>";
        echo    "<span class='list-group-item-heading'><b>". utf8_encode($getInfo['title'])."</b><br /></span>";
        echo    "<span class='list-group-item-text'>". utf8_encode($getInfo['content'])."&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>". date("d/m/Y", $getInfo['date'])."</small></span>";
        echo    "</span>";
    } 
?>
```

in the database the date is stored into an int(11) and it look like this "1465929874" now as you can imagine I did not design the first part I just try to make it do what I need it to do.

Comment: dates with a `/` separator will be treated as US format (`m/d/Y`) by strtotime()

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure as to why you are converting them to d/m/Y format to store in a variable, when you aren't using that variable in any other place than to check.

You should just be able to do:

```
//Date stored in database
$NewsDate           = strtotime($getInfo['date']);

// The date stored into the DB + 10 days
$NewsDatePlus10     = strtotime($NewsDate) + (86400 * 10); 

//Now you have a timestamp here.
if ($NewsDate < $NewsDatePlus10) {
      //Code here               
} else {
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do maths with text and you won't need to reinvent the wheel:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$NewsDate = new DateTimeImmutable($getInfo['date']);
$NewsDatePlus10 = $NewsDate->modify('+10 days');
if ($NewsDate <= $NewsDatePlus10) {
} else {
}
```

Make sure that `$getInfo['date']` comes in an unambiguous format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your full answer:

```
 <?php
    $today = new DateTime();
    $NewsDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($getInfo['date']));
    $NewsDatePlus10 = $NewsDate->modify('+10 days');

            if ($NewsDate <= $NewsDatePlus10) {
                echo    "<span class='list-group-item-heading'><b>". utf8_encode($getInfo['title'])."</b><br /></span>";
                echo    "<span class='list-group-item-text'>". utf8_encode($getInfo['content'])."&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>". date("d/m/Y", $getInfo['date'])."</small></span>";                           
            } else {
                echo    "<span style='color:red;'>";
                echo    "<span class='list-group-item-heading'><b>". utf8_encode($getInfo['title'])."</b><br /></span>";
                echo    "<span class='list-group-item-text'>". utf8_encode($getInfo['content'])."&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>". date("d/m/Y", $getInfo['date'])."</small></span>";
                echo    "</span>";
            } 
        ?>
```

**But please check your date format when you are retrieving.**

When you want to add dates, 
For e.g. `$NewDate=Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));`

For decrease the dates, For e.g. `$NewDate=Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-3 days"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example as per your need. this will give you the number of days old you db date is.

```
$now = time(); // current time 
$your_date = strtotime("15-09-2016"); // db date
$datediff = $now - $your_date;
$no_of_days =  floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

if($no_of_days > 10){ echo 'red';}
else {  echo 'black';}
```